# Submitting a form with JQuery Ajax results in multiple requests (and submissions)

Tags: jquery, ajax, recursion, form-submit, onsubmit

I have run into an issue with JQuery form submissions and have found no answers anywhere . If someone could shed some light on this, it would be highly appreciated.

The issue: The first time I submit the form, it works fine. But **if I submit the same form a second time, it sends 2 requests, 3 requests the third time, and so forth.**

Script:

```
    function postInvokeFunctionForm(functionId){
      var formId = "#"+functionId+"-form";
      var formUrl = "invokeFunction.html?functionId="+functionId
      $(formId).submit(
        function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: formUrl,
                data: $(formId).serialize(),
                success: function (data){
                 alert('successfully invoked function!' + data);
                }
            });
            return false;
           }
        );
   }
```

Dynamically generated form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="xxxxx-form" class="invokeFunctionForm">
<input name="functionId" value="xxxxx" readonly="readonly" style="visibility: hidden;" type="text">
<input value="Invoke" onclick="postInvokeFunctionForm(xxxxx);" type="submit">
</form>
```

This obviously is undesirable. The only solution I can think of, id to re-render the (dynamically generated) form after being submitted, but that would be an expensive operation.

Is this a known issue with JQuery ajax submissions or am I missing something obvious? Is there perhaps some form of recursion taking place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each time you click the button, the code is calling your function.  In that function the line `$(formId).submit(...);` is binding the event to the form's submit action.  This happens every time you click, adding multiple "submit" events to the form.  You need to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the action first.  So you could call `$(formId).unbind('submit').submit(...);` instead.

Comment: Thanks, it's still fresh in my mind from coding and suffering from something similar myself earlier in the week :)

Answer (score 2):

When you do this

```
$(formId).submit(function(){})
```

You are adding the function to the `submit` event.
When you click in the `submit` button you are adding a this `function` and submitting through the default behavior of `input type="submit"`. When you click again you add the same `function` to the `submit` event. So when you click one time you have one `function` in the `submit` event, when you click two times you have two `functions`.

That said you can do what you want like this:

```
$('#inputInvokeId').submit(function(){
var formUrl = "invokeFunction.html?functionId="+inputInvokeId;
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: formUrl,
                data: $(formId).serialize(),
                success: function (data){
                 alert('successfully invoked function!' + data);
                }
            });
            return false;
           }

})

<form action="" method="post" id="xxxxx-form" class="invokeFunctionForm">
<input name="functionId" value="xxxxx" readonly="readonly" style="visibility: hidden;" type="text">
<input value="Invoke" id="inputInvokeId" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Excellent explanation! That explains everything! I'm gonna go try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input value="Invoke" onclick="postInvokeFunctionForm(xxxxx);" type="submit">
```

to

```
<input value="Invoke" onclick="postInvokeFunctionForm(xxxxx);" type="button">
```

The < input type="submit" > is what is causing the double submit.

Comment: That may be the cause if you had a double submit each time, but as the question states in bold the number of submissions starts of at 1 and increases by one each click - looking like a multiple event bind issue.

Comment: Multiple binding of the event is the correct answer yes.  It is a good idea to change the "submit" to "button" none the less if you use javascript to submit the form.